# Compare date stored as an integer with a datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a column having datatype integer which is in the format yyyymm (e.g. 201905). I want to check if this column is in between start and end date i.e.:

```
case 
  when [cov_yyyymm] between [start_dt] and [end_dt] then 'Period1'
  else 'OtherPeriod' 
end
```

note: start and end dates are datetime

I have tried converting the Int to datetime/date. similarly vice versa from date to int and still could not get it to work.

I expect to use a CASE statement to compare if the Integer is in between 2 dates.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: If it is a number that represents a date, then treat it as a date like Salman shows below.  You were taking the right approach by trying to cast it.

Comment: Do you have data like period `201905` and dates `2019-05-03` and `2019-05-20` for example? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert it to datetime like so:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(201905 AS VARCHAR(6)) + '01' AS DATETIME)
```

And compare with datetime columns like so:

```
WHERE CAST(CAST(201905 AS VARCHAR(6)) + '01' AS DATETIME) BETWEEN start_dt AND end_dt
```

Comment: Thanks Salman. Double casting it did the trick...I guess i was trying to Convert it more than Cast it.

Answer (score 0):

Your period is in `yyyymm` format, so next statement is another possible approach. This approach is useful when period and dates are from one month - like period `201905` and dates `2019-05-03` and `2019-05-20`. Adding a day (first or last day of month) to an integer period (yyymm) and comparing with datetime values is not always correct.

```
case 
  when [cov_yyyymm] between 
      (YEAR([start_dt])*100 + MONTH([start_dt])) and 
      (YEAR([end_dt])*100 + MONTH([end_dt])) then 'Period1'
  else 'OtherPeriod' 
end
```